# Express not handling errors sent inside controllers or other classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, error-handling

When i call a rout and send a error, it calls the error middleware, for exemple:

```
# routes.ts
// sending an error
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    throw new BadRequestError("teste")
})
```

This calls the errorMiddleware and threats the error.
But when I send from the controller, like this:

```
# UserController.ts
export class UserController {
    static async registerNewUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const newUser = new User(req.body)

        const alreadyExists = await User.findUser(newUser)

        if (alreadyExists) {
            throw new BadRequestError("teste")
        }
    }
}
```

And call a route for it like this:

```
# routes.ts
router.post('/register', UserController.registerNewUser)
```

The middleware is never called and application crashes.
My app.ts code:

```
# app.ts
const app = express()

app.use(express.json());

app.use(router)

app.use(errorMiddleware)

export { app }
```

My server.ts code:

```
# server.ts
import { app } from "./app";

const PORT = process.env.PORT

app.listen (PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`))
```

I've tried to change the error middleware and add another one as well. None of these worked
Also tried to take out the errors from subclasses and pass it to controllers, but got the same result

I expect to send an error from any class inside my API and handle it with an middleware

Comment: Use express v5, which handles promise rejections properly

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

install the express-async-error library.

Comment: Please don't add _thanks_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](/help/why-vote).

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35081315)